# lightning component navigate button is not working

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I created a Lightning component and a button "create New Field" is not at all working in the component.

Can anyone guide me on this issue if possible please.

my component:

```
<div class="slds-grid">
    <!-- Go to create new field cmp -->
    <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.accountId.length > 0}">
            <ui:button label="Create New Field"
                class="slds-button slds-button--brand slds-button--small"
                press="{!c.goToFieldCmp}"/>
    </aura:renderIf>
```

controller.Js

```
({

goToFieldCmp : function(component, event, helper) {
    var evt = $A.get("e.c:trac_NavigateToCreateField");
    evt.setParams({
       accountId: component.get("v.accountId"),
       accountName: component.get("v.accountName")
    });
    evt.fire();  
}, 

goToOpportunityCmp : function(component, event, helper) {            
    var evt = $A.get("e.c:trac_NavigateToCreateOpp");
    evt.setParams({
          accountId: component.get("v.accountId"),
          fieldId: component.get("v.fieldId"),
          fieldName: component.get("v.fieldName"),
          accountName: component.get("v.accountName")
    });
  evt.fire(); 


},
```

Event:

```
<aura:event type="APPLICATION" description="Event template" >
<aura:attribute name="accountId" type="Id"/>
<aura:attribute name="accountName" type="String"/>
```

Comment: Where do you want to navigate? Are you trying to navigate to Account detail page?

Comment: You are using very old and deprecated components. `<aura:renderIf>` is deprecated, and the entire `<ui:*>` component set is being deprecated as well.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide more details as to what "not working" means. Does the button display? Does it fire an event? What receives the event?

Comment: @DavidReed, Yes the buttons are getting displayed but the moment I click the button nothing is working on actually

Comment: Please **[edit] your question** to provide the _all_ of the details requested by commenters.